# Publish website in GitHub Pages results in black screen. Is NPM the issue?

Tags: npm, github-pages

I have a webpage that comprises a three.js scene with a dat.gui menu and using OrbitControls. The libraries are imported via NPM.
It loads fine locally, but when I publish the project to GitHub Pages, I get a black screen in the browser.

Is the problem coming from the fact that I'm using NPM?
What is the solution?

Comment: need more info, what's the error msg?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It was something else completely unrelated. Didn't realize that I had to bundle my JS files before publishing online.